# Connection is not opening for SQL server 2016 with port 1600 using VB.Net

Tags: sql-server-2016

Connection is not opening when I try to open using VB.Net to MS SQL server 2016 with port 1600. My connection string is

```
Public glob_connection_string As String = "Server=learningserver.com,1600;Database=learning_db;User ID=read_only;Password=read_only;"
```

Visual studio: 2010
MS SQL server: 2016

TCP/IP port also enabled.

Could you please help what's wrong with this connection?

Comment: And the error message is?

Comment: On UI, it says "The connection cannot be used to perform this operation. It is either closed or invalid in this context". On debug mode "DefaultDatabase = {"Operation is not allowed when the object is closed."}"

Comment: Did you call `connection.Open()`? Can you show that code?

Answer (score 0):

The default Sql Server port is 1433. It is possible to change this port, but it's not recommended. If you do change the port, also make sure you open up the port on any firewalls which may be in play.

Additionally, the normal syntax for specifying  a port in a uri is a colon (`:`) rather than a comma.

```
​Server=learningserver.com:1600;Database=learning_db;User ID=...;Password=...;
```

Comment: I have replaced comma(,) with colon(:), still same error

Comment: DBA team migrated DB from 2008 to 2016 and they wanted to use port 1600 not the default port 1433 as 1600 is more secure. I did not use any port when I was using 2008 server, now I have to use 1600 but DB connection is not opening.

Answer (score 0):

It's solved after updating SQL native client to 11- ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server. And connection string is

Public glob_connection_string As String = "PROVIDER=SQLNCLI11;Server=99.99.99.99,1600;Database=learning_db;User ID=read_only;Password=read_only;Persist Security Info=False"

Port is used with comma (,) not with colon(:).